# valid_password? function does not increment failed_attempts attr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, rubygems, devise-confirmable

Using Devise 4.8.1 and Rails 7.0.3, I had done the steps from this wiki [How To: Add :lockable to Users](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:lockable-to-Users) before and I did a custom password verification that would lock the user access after 5 failed attempts. Previously, the `valid_password?` function worked and could increment the `failed_attempts` attribute on the `users` table, be it in rails console or controller (do at backend) but now it does not work.

Here's my code:

```
data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

user = User.find_for_authentication(email: data['email'])
retries_remaining = 5
failed_attempts = data['failed_attempts'] + 1

if user.valid_password?(data['password']) 
    render json: { "status" => true }
else
    if failed_attempts >= retries_remaining
        user.lock_access!(opts: { send_instructions: false })
        user.send_unlock_instructions
        render json: { "status" => false, "redirect_path" => root_path }
    else
        if (failed_attempts + 2) >= retries_remaining
            msg = "There are #{retries_remaining - failed_attempts} retries remaining."
        else 
            msg = 'Password is not matching.'
        end
        render json: { "status" => false, "message" => msg }
    end
end
```

The `retries_remaining` and `failed_attempts` variables are only for my checker. But, I want if users have attempted 3 times and left the page, the `failed_attempts` attribute also increments too so that if they go back to this page, they only have 2 retries remaining.

Any clues on this issue?